# Get total rows filtered by if() statement in google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got this fn().

Is there any simple way to return the number of filtered rows by this conditional statement in Google app scripts?

```
function getGlobers(globers, project){

  var body = "";

  var data  = globers.getValues();

  for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){

    if( data[i][2] == project ){

      body += "<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">" + data[i].join("</td><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr>";

    }

  } 

  return body;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example (see comments in code)

```
function getGlobers(globers, project){
  var body = "";
  var n = 0; // use a variable to count
  var data  = globers.getValues();
  for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if( data[i][2] == project ){
      n++;// increment each time condition is true
      body += "<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">" + data[i].join("</td><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr>";
    }
  } 
  return [body,n];// return an array of 2 values
}
```

Usage :

```
  var result =  getGlobers(range,project);
  Logger.log('array result = '+result);
  Logger.log('body (string) = '+result[0]);
  Logger.log('length (integer) = '+result[1]);
```

note : instead of an array you could also return an object with 2 properties... a matter of choice.

**EDIT :** an example using object properties :

```
function getGlobers(globers, project){
  var body = "";
  var n = 0;
  var result = {};
  var data  = globers.getValues();
  for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
    if( data[i][2] == project ){
      n++;
      body += "<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">" + data[i].join("</td><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr>";
    }
  } 
  result['body'] = body;
  result['length'] = n;
  return result;
}
```

Usage :

```
  var result =  getGlobers(range,project);
  Logger.log('body = '+result.body);
  Logger.log('length = '+result.length);
```